# Android Post Form data when network is not available

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I have a simple form with 4 fields that i submit to remote mysql data on submit. When there is no connection available this form fails to send data. I know i can store data in sqlite, but i'm not sure how to send this data to mysql db when app is not running and network is available? Can anyone point me to some samples that i can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Register a broadcast receiver for `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`. Then check if network if available, and send saved data, if any. Or, simply check for saved data and send on  the next run of your app.

Comment: thanks, i got one doubt will those receiver event get called whenever network change? I want to only send when data is available and not run this code on every network change event.

Comment: You get notified, and you need to check what exactly happened in your code: connectivity lost, changed, etc. Only post data when it makes sense. Use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html for this.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to send your data anywhere if your application is not running. You may try instead to look for saved data every time your application starts, and send it if such data exists and network connection is available.

What happens to the saved data if the user does not start your application anymore? Nothing, probably (s)he does not need it anyway.